# Changing titles of chapters and parts from onehalfspaced to single spaced

Tags: sectioning, memoir, line-spacing

Is there a simple solution for making the titlename of parts and chapters singlespaced but the text onehalfspaced without having to add `\SingleSpace` to every titlename. I have found a solution that works adequately for sections which is:

```
\renewcommand\secheadstyle{\setSpacing{0.95}\Large\bfseries\memRTLraggedright}
```

I need it not to overule any costumization with the ToC, the header etc. It should only impact the way titles of parts and sections asre displayed on the page, not in the ToC or in headers or anywhere else.

Minimal functional doc:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn,twoside,final]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newcent}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[textwidth=14cm,textheight=22cm]{geometry} 

\chapterstyle{hangnum}
\OnehalfSpacing

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Long title of the chapter, that breaks the line and should be single  spaced instead of onehalfspaced}
Text that is onehalfspaced just like it should be. Nothing like a piece of text that is like it should be. Text that is onehalfspaced just like it should be. Nothing like a piece of text that is like it should be. Text that is onehalfspaced just like it should be. Nothing like a piece of text that is like it should be.
\section{A Long section title of the chapter, with the same problem as the title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW: `OnehalfSpace` is an environment, use `\OnehalfSpacing`, then you do not get that `\end occurred inside a group at level 1` in the log.

Comment: I did actually use \OnehalfSpacing in my document. I'll edit it now..

Comment: But do you have a possible solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Teach `memoir` to use single spacing in titles:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn,twoside,final]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newcent}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[textwidth=14cm,textheight=22cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{color} % just for the example

\chapterstyle{hangnum}
\preto\chaptitlefont{\linespread{1}}
\setsechook{\linespread{1}}

\OnehalfSpacing

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Long title of the chapter, that breaks the line and 
should be single spaced instead of onehalfspaced}

Text that is onehalf spaced just like it should \textit{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{not}}} be. Nothing 
like a piece of text that is like it should be. Text that is onehalfspaced just like it 
should be. Nothing like a piece of text that is like it should be. Text that is onehalfspaced 
just like it should be. Nothing like a piece of text that is like it should be.

\section{A Long section title of the chapter, with the same problem as the title}

\end{document}
```

You may want to do similarly for subsections and lower levels.

[image]

If you can, avoid enlarged leading.

Comment: This solution worked for 5 minutes... but now, suddenly, I have whole bunch of over and underful boxes...

Comment: @Faergen Without any clue it's difficult to say something.

Comment: Is there any way I could post my document and show you? It seems the error goes away, if I delete my bibliography... but no error shows up in the error box or log... even latex doesn't know what's wrong. And I've tried deleting all the auxiliary files, but it didn't help. And it doesn't help removing the citations either, so the bibliography would be empty

Comment: I tried adding a bibliography, but I notice nothing strange. Please, try producing a minimal example and open a new question.